# SilverStripe 3.* SMTP Configuration

Tags: smtp, silverstripe

https://github.com/xeraa/silverstripe-smtp this add on generates Server error. Is there any other SMTP module available for version 3.*?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this https://github.com/azt3k/abc-silverstripe-mailer
It will install PHPMailer dependance.